# How to derive partially defined functions

Tags: analysis, derivatives

How would I derive a function like

$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2y^2 - x^2y^2}{x^2 + y^2} f(0,0) = 0$

with respect to x or y?

Doing it for the "normally" define part is easy. But how do I take care of the special case f(0,0)?

Comment: What do you mean by "derive a function"? Do you mean to find the partial derivative?

Comment: Seing as your function is equal to $0$ everywhere, I don't think you're going to have much of a problem in this case. In the more general case, as long as $f$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$, you need to look at the limit
$$
\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x \text{ or } y}f(x, y)
$$
If it exists, then that limit is the derivative of $f$ at the origin. If it doesn't, then $f$ isn't differentiable at the origin.

Comment: @Arthur I randomly picked an example (though as you pointed out this one is bad). I was interrested in how the general solution to this would be (how do I treat that special case f(0,0) = 0)

Comment: @mathandzen yes I do mean the partial derivate

Comment: @Sim That is what the second sentence in that comment says. You have to look at the derivatives in the immediate surrounding area and see if they continuously permit a single derivative at the origin. If they do, then that is what your derivative is. If they don't, then $f$ is not differentiable at the origin. Again, of course, $f$ needs to be continuous for this to make any sense in the first place.